# Angular2 Update Template from Service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm new to Angular2, and started off writing an app where all methods were in `main.ts`, and that file in turn referenced its view in `main.html`. I refactored this app into subcomponents and services. So, I now have:

```
- app.component.ts
- app.html
- sub.component.ts
- sub.html
- data.service.ts
```

`sub.component` is included as a directive in `app.component`. `app.compontent` injects `data.service` and I can call the service from a click event in `app.component`.

**The Question**

Previously, I could update a progress bar on the view from a function in the component. Now that the function is in its own service, how do I update the user on the progress of the long-running (recursive) method in the service? I assume I have to pass the progress from the service to `app.component` or `sub.component`, but how is this meant to be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/EventEmitter-class.html) to pass values to the component. Create emitter in your service and subscribe to it in the component.

```
// data.service.ts
class DataService() {
  progress = new EventEmitter();

  longRunningMethod() {
    this.progress.emit(value);
  }
}

// app.component.ts
class AppComponent() {
  constructor(service: DataService) {
    service.progress.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need subscribe to service from component ( or both component ).

You can provide service on bootstrap ( and it will be available to all your components )

```
bootstrap(App, [YourService]);
```

Or to provide it in component with provide:

```
@Component({selector: "cmp", provide: [YourService]})
```

Take a look on this example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/d4jIDQ4lSuXUDttKFAS6?p=preview

Comment: Sure, no problem. Be careful about one thing: If you provide service in application bootstrap - it is same object of that class in all components where you subscribe. If you provide it per component, you are creating new object each time.